# How to transcode audio files in a batch?

Tags: soundconverter

I'd use Sound Converter except it just hangs. It works fine for the odd file or two, but I need to do a lot of files from different directories and it just doesn't like it.

I'm searching for all .ogg files and want them transcoding to AAC with tags intact. (I prefer Vorbis but slack old Sony haven't bothered adding the codec to my car stereo...)

So is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Clementine](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clementine/)

It's a little awkward, but it can be done as follows.

1. Make a playlist of all the music you want.
2. Select all items in the playlist, right click and choose *Organise files...*
3. Make a **copy** of all the files in a new directory, but removing the directory nesting, i.e. so they will all be in one directory. I do this by using
   `convert_these/%artist__%album__{%track - }%title.%extension`
4. Next choose *Tools menu* → *Transcode Music*. From this dialogue box you can add all the files from your new `convert_these` directory, and it will make converted copies along side these files.
5. You can then delete all the copied originals from your `convert_these` folder with your favourite file manager.
6. Finally, you can add all these new files into a new playlist, and use the *Organise files...` tool again to move them into whatever folder structure you need.